# ERROR: syntax error at or near "text" Position: 314

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I wrote a query which is supposed to perform a check for every value in array if it is present in any table, but I get

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "text"
```

Could you please suggest what am I doing wrong?

My query:

```
DECLARE
  words text[];
  w text;
BEGIN
  words := string_to_array('a b c', ' ');
    FOR EACH w IN array(words) LOOP
      EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE w IN (last_name, first_name, middle_name)';
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

**UPD**

Forgot to point it out, it should be possible to put any sting in **words** variable. Query should work for string like `'a b c'` or `'a'` or `'bc a d'`. **Sorry.**

Comment: From the error, one of the lines in the `DECLARE` block, since that's the only occurrence of "text" I see, has a syntax error around it. I would verify that what you have there is valid syntax.

Comment: An anonymous PL/pgSQL block needs to be written in a [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the point for the procedure and the loop. As I understand your question, you can get the result that you want with a straight query, like so:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (
    select 1
    from unnest(string_to_array('a b c', ' ')) x(val)
    where x.val in (u.last_name, u.first_name, u.middle_name)
)
```

Comment: I think you don't even need the unnest: `where array[u.last_name, u.first_name, u.middle_name] && string_to_array('....', ' ')`